PHP receives no parameter via AJAX
I try to hand over a parameter, a String, that is determined by user input via Ajax to a PHP Programm, but the php does not receive the parameter I try to handover. Then Ajax should return a JSON
const category = document.getElementById('genreSelect').value;

            $.ajax({  
            type: 'GET',  
            url: 'button.php', 
            data: { category: category } ,
            success: function(response) {                
            console.log(response);
                

    }
});

<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$kate ="";
if(isset($_POST['category'])) {
        $name = $_POST['category'];
        $kate =$name;
        echo $name;
    } else {
        echo "No name parameter received.";
    }
echo json_encode($kate);
?>

I have tried several other Ajax commands, but they did not work.

How are you calling the AJAX code? Is it in an event listener? Are you assigning category after the user makes their selection?

Get rid of all the echo statements except for the JSON.

You need to use type: 'POST', not GET. Or use $_GET in PHP.

I use GET instead but it sill does not work.

I use GET instead instead of what? your JS code as shown already uses GET ... change it to POST or change the PHP to use $_GET

I changed PHP to use GET.

What is the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] returning in your php file? var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']), does it equal POST or GET?

Please post a [mre] showing how you're calling this.

Your
type: 'GET'

specifies that you are sending a GET request, whereas on the other side you expect a POST parameter with $_POST['category']. Change your request type to POST, like:
type: 'POST'

and then test... Open your browser dev tools, navigate to the Network tab and then click on your submit button. See whether you get some errors in the console due to some problems and whether you see a new request appearing in the Network tab.
If you see a new request, verify the payload of that request, whether it contains the category you wanted to pass and also verify the URL where you wanted to send your request whether it actually executes your server-side code. You can use a debugger tool for that purpose, like xdebug.

you only need change POST for GET
if(isset($_GET['category'])) {
        $name = $_GET['category'];


I have tried this, but it still does not work out. Actually, the php should just return it and display it in the JS console, so i can it has been read by the PHP, but i get no sign on the console and php says, it could not receive the parameter.
